# Exclude resources from java maven build

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jar

There seem to be many many posts about similar questions however I have been unable to find exactly what I am looking for.

Basically, I have a Java Application built using Maven in Eclipse. When I execute the project from withing Eclipse it works correctly as it can find all files in my resources directory. When I do a normal jar with dependencies build using maven it also works. However, in the final item I cannot get this to work:

I would like the resources to be excluded from the main executable jar and placed into a directory on the same level as the jar itself. This was a user can just make changes to the settings and execute the jar, so:

```
|--root level
 |-Jar
 |-resources
  |-log4j.properties
  |-settings.properties
```

I have the maven-jar-plugin doing this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
        <index>true</index>
        <manifest>
            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
            <mainClass>com.org.interfaces.SharepointClient.App</mainClass>
            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
        </manifest>
        <manifestEntries>
            <mode>development</mode>
            <url>http://org.com</url>
            <key>value</key>
            <Class-Path>resources/settings.properties resources/log4j.properties</Class-Path>
        </manifestEntries>
        </archive>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>settings.properties</exclude>
            <exclude>log4j.properties</exclude>
        </excludes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

And I have the maven-assembly-plugin creating the resources directory with all the resource files.

The project compiles and generates the directory structure as I want it however, the class files are unable to locate anything in the resources directory even though I specifically added them the classpath in the manifest.mf

This is the Manifest for details:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Build-Jdk: 1.7.0_17
Class-Path: resources/settings.properties resources/log4j.properties 
 lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar lib/jaxws-api-2.2.11.jar lib/jaxb-api-2.2.9.ja
 r lib/javax.xml.soap-api-1.3.5.jar lib/javax.annotation-api-1.2-b03
 .jar lib/jsr181-api-1.0-MR1.jar lib/saxon-9.1.0.8.jar lib/saxon-9.1
 .0.8-dom.jar
Created-By: Apache Maven 3.0.5
Main-Class: com.org.interfaces.SharepointClient.App
key: value
url: http://org.com
mode: development
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
```

When Executed I receive an error on this line of code:
    PropertyLoader.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("settings.properties");

The error is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.Properties$LineReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Properties.load0(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Properties.load(Unknown Source)
    at com.org.interfaces.SharepointClient.PropertyLoader.getProps(PropertyLoader.java:29)
```

EDIT:
I am only having trouble getting java to load resources, not dependencies. Those appear to load correctly.

Comment: Have you tried including just "resources/" in the class path?

Comment: I have tried, but nothing seems to include these resources. It is like the classpath is getting overwritten by something.

Comment: Just to verify the class path, check what the value of ` System.getProperty("java.class.path")` is from within the java app. You might also try using `getSystemResourceAsStream(String name)`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are making this more difficult that it need be. Take a look at this http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html. You should simply add all of your dependencies to the pom.xml file. This way, whenever you transport your code, maven will use the pom.xml file to rebuild the project with all of your dependencies. http://mvnrepository.com/ makes it even easier. All you have to do is search for the dependency in the repository, and copy it into your pom file.

Comment: I appreciate the reply but, the problem is not the dependencies. I have maven acquiring the dependencies according the instructions. I  am having trouble getting resources, like properties files, on the classpath when they are not bundled with the main jar file